# How to add these three files properly?"Default.png, Default-568h@2x.png, Default@2x.png" for universal app for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, splash-screen, default.png

I added "Default.png, Default-568h@2x.png, Default@2x.png"  these three files in my universal project for splash image, I have three diffrent image and the resolution exactly the same as mention in apple docs, for iPad 768 * 1024 , for iphone-4s -> 320 * 480 , for iphone 5-> 640 * 1136.

But my problem is that when I rum on iphone4s- iphone5 the splash rum properly, but when I run on Ipad the Deafault.png splash not showing instead of it takes reference from Default-568h@2x.png. The Default-568h@2x.png is showing on the iPad instead of Deafault.png and the image got blur and shrink on ipad also, beacuse Deafault.png not showing. How to slove this problem.

Any Idea or suggestion from experts would be highly welcome.

Comment: select splash screens from application summery-> launch images then it will display correct images

Comment: Hi, when I slect Image Default.png the yellow mark is showing on the first and on the second and third the yellow mark is not showing. The first I make is for iPad Deafult.png and the resolution is 768 * 1024

Comment: ya because size default.png is not proper size as it required

Comment: what is the proper size?

Comment: iPhone      320x480
iPhone (ratina)  640x960
iPhone5 (ratina) 640x1136

iPad      768x1024
iPad (ratina)  1536x2048

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First I would like to suggest that,
2. Preapre all Images,
3. Select Project from Project Navigator And Go to Summary and scroll down this
   screen appears, then right click on that and choose file from your
   computer it will automatically copied to project and it will entered
   in plist file also..
4. if your application is universal then you have
   to set for iPhone and iPad Both.
   `
   [image]

Comment: Hi, when I slect Image Default.png the yellow mark is showing on the first and on the second and third the yellow mark is not showing. The first I make is for iPad Deafult.png and the resolution is 768 * 1024

Comment: Yellow mark showing it means your image you have selected is not appropriate size. if you want to know what size it should be just move mouse on that perticuler image it will give suggestion...Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Launch image naming should be similar like this for universal application.

```
iPhone > Default~iPhone.png,Default@2x~iPhone.png & Default-568h@2x.png.
iPad > Default-Portrait~iPad.png,Default-Portrait@2x~iPad.png,Default-Landscape~iPad.png,Default-Landscape@2x~iPad.png
```

Please refere the following link for more details regarding image resolutions

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

and for image naming conventions use the following link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

Comment: could you please tell me the resolutions also? Just want to confirm.

Comment: create 3 different images for iPhone, Default~iPhone.png,Default@2x~iPhone.png & Default-568h@2x.png.And Different for iPad Default~ipad.png and Default@2x~iPad.png and use those images

Answer (score 1):

See the offical document at chapter **App Launch (Default) Images**:
[App Launch (Default) Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12%3E)

Only you should do is set the launch image a proper name with relative size, then add those images to the project. Xcode will help you to display it correctly when app launching.