# Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png location

Tags: ios

I put localisation file with Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png to Englisj.lproj, French.lproj etc

[image]

but validation reports as image above

if I put Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png to root path of project.
Validation is ok, but Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png localisation is invalid,

I check Englisj.lproj, French.lprojm Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png are there,

but when I open 'show package content' of generated app, found that there is no Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png in French.lproj

[image]

is there any person met the same problem

Your comment welcome

Comment: Are the images added to your project target? (Check this by selecting the launch images in your french.lproj folder and then check the file properties pane if the project target is checked under Target Membership)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localized text strings - String resources are stored in a special type of file known as a strings file. A strings file is a text file with a .strings filename extension. Any string resources that might be displayed to the user should be placed in strings files. For more information, see “Localizing String Resources.”

[image]

add images separated folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894176/how-to-add-these-three-files-properlydefault-png-default-568h2x-png-default) could help you how to add launch images.

But to localize the launch images you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language)